# Append texts tab-delimited text file column wise in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, large-files, streamreader

I have a tab-delimited text file of size of many GBs. Task here is to append header texts to each column. As of now, I use StreamReader to read line by line and append headers to each column. It takes a lot of time as of now. Is there a way to make it faster ? I was thinking if there is a way to process the file column-wise. One way would be to import the file in database table and then bcp out the data after appending the headers. Is there any other better way, probably by calling powershell, awk/sed in C# code ?

Code is as follows :

```
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@FilePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
  string mainLine = sr.ReadLine();
  string[] fileHeaders = mainLine.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
  string newLine = "";

  System.IO.StreamWriter outFileSw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@outFile);

  while (!sr.EndOfStream)
  {
     mainLine = sr.ReadLine();
     string[] originalLine = mainLine.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

     newLine = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaders.Length; i++)
     {
          if(fileHeaders[i].Trim() != "")
           newLine = newLine + fileHeaders[i].Trim() + "=" + originalLine[i].Trim() + "&";
     }

 outFileSw.WriteLine(newLine.Remove(newLine.Length - 1));
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing else operating on just text files is going to be significantly faster - fundamentally you've *got* to read the whole of the input file, and you've *got* to create a whole new output file, as you can't "insert" text for each column.

Using a database would almost certainly be a better idea in general, but adding a column could still end up being a relatively slow business.

You can improve how you're dealing with each line, however. In this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaders.Length; i++)
{
    if(fileHeaders[i].Trim() != "")
         newLine = newLine + fileHeaders[i].Trim() + "=" + originalLine[i].Trim() + "&";
}
```

... you're using string concatenation in a loop, which will be slow if there's a large number of columns. Using a `StringBuilder` is very likely to be more efficient. Additionally, there's no need to call `Trim()` on every string in `fileHeaders` on every line. You can just work out which columns you want *once*, trim the header appropriately, and filter that way.

Comment: @kanu: Well they would still have to write out the whole file again, if you insert a character. (Or more accurately, they'd have to write out the whole file from that point onwards.)

Comment: Thanks..Looks like the StreamReader should be the way to go as the files are about of 50 - 100 GB and database table queries will also take time for the imported data.